# Is there any alternative to merge multiple rows into a single row without using groupBy() & collect_list() in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to merge multiple rows into a single row after grouping data on a different column.

```
col1 col2
  A   1
  A   2
  B   1
  B   3
```

to

```
col1 col2
  A   1,2
  B   1,3
```

By using the below code:

```
df = spark.sql("select col1, col2, col3,...., colN from tablename where col3 = 'ABCD' limit 1000")
df.select('col1','col2').groupby('col1').agg(psf.concat_ws(', ', psf.collect_list(df.col2))).display()
```

This is working fine when there is less data.
But if I try to increase the number of rows to 1million, the code fails with the exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Results too large
```

Is there any alternative to merge multiple rows into a single row in spark without using the combination of `groupby()` & `collect_list()`

Comment: It is a bit unclear, what you really want to achieve with this analysis. It sounds like your aggregation just creates a column with VERY long strings and it escapes me why you would want that. Adding a more meaningful aggregation might solve your problem.

Comment: Furthermore, the `display()` command is probably what gets you the error, see this possibly-related [issue](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues/5826). I think (but it's only a supposition) that if you do not `show()` or `display()` the results, you should still be able to obtain the dataframe you want.